# Launching different service host with the same contract fails

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to write a generic host process (WinForm) which host different WCF Service implementation of the same contract.
When I run the first one it works OK, but when I launch the other one (in parallel) with a different address is throws that I use the same address twice (addr and port) -> path is different though..

```
    private bool InitializeServiceHost()
    {
        bool isInitialized = true;
        try
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("Loading service DLL {0} and class {1}", _dllPath, _serviceClassName);
            var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(_dllPath);
            _service = (IGfnService) asm.CreateInstance(_serviceClassName);
            if (_service == null)
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not instansiate {0} from DLL {1}", _serviceClassName, _dllPath));

            _service.Init(_myGuidStr);
            Uri uri = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9085/GfnService/" + _myGuidStr);

            var host = new ServiceHost(_service, uri);

            Log.InfoFormat("About to open host, State: {0}, URI: {1} ", host.State, uri);
            host.Open();
            _serviceUri = uri.ToString();
            Log.InfoFormat("Gfn service started successfully, State: {0}, URI: {1} ", host.State, uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            isInitialized = false;
            Application.Exit();
        }
        return isInitialized;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: Have you seen this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dkaufman/archive/2008/06/13/hosting-multiple-service-implementation-on-the-same-port-with-wcf.aspx)? Seems like what you are trying to do is feasible. The one difference in your implementation is that your URL format is "http://<server>:<port>/<service>/<guid>" i.e. there is a "/" between the service and guid. Have you tried removing this "/"? I assume the service name is what follows the port, so the "/" might be causing all your services to be treated as the same.

Comment: Nop! did not work. same error.... also the blog does not seems to do the same...

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. Do you have a mex endpoint configured for any service?

Comment: No, it works without it. Minimal configuration scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! it works now! (thanks to all commenters)

```
           var host = new ServiceHost(_service);
            Log.Info("Service host generated.");

            ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = host.Description.Endpoints.Find(typeof(IGfnService));
            if (serviceEndpoint == null)
            {
                serviceEndpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IGfnService), new NetTcpBinding
                {
                    MaxConnections = 10,
                    PortSharingEnabled = true
                }, uri);
                Log.InfoFormat("Endpoint [{0}] added", serviceEndpoint);
            }
```

The trick was to add the PortSharingEnabled! so the two instances can share the same port! (I should have though about it before, but at least I got a chance to share!)

Thanks!